# Should I add deleted files to stage area?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, versioning

I'm confused about Git.

I know that changed files or new files must be added to stage area, but what about deleted files? Should I add deleted files to the staging area too?

Here is a hypothetical scenario:

```
myproject-dir/app/contorller/controller_1.php
myproject-dir/app/contorller/controller_2.php
```

If I remove/delete `controller_1.php` from my `myproject-dir/app/controller/`, should I add this file to next commit?

Comment: Yes. To remove a tracked file from version control, you must stage the *deletion* of that file; saying "stage the deletion of a file" is less confusing than saying "add a deleted file to staging area".

Comment: Couldn't you try that by yourself? What happens when you add it? What happens when you don't? What's your conclusion?

Comment: @JBNizet I just have edited

Comment: Normally you would remove files with `git rm` which stages them automatically.  What you are describing sounds like you are using normal `rm`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should think about the staging area more as something were you add *changes* to. So adding a file to the repository is a *change* where you add a file. Modifying a file in the repository is a *change* where you modify a file. And deleting a file from the repository is a *change* where you delete the file.

So yes, for the repository to recognize that the file is actually removed from the repository in a commit, you need to *add* the *file removal* to the index.

You can do that using `git rm`:

```
git rm path/to/file
```

If you—for whatever reason—want to keep the file on the disk when removing it from the repository, you can use the `--cached` option to keep it.

```
git rm --cached path/to/file
```

If the file is already physically deleted from the disk, you can still use `git rm` as above to add the removal to the index. You can also use the update capability of `git add` to discover updates to tracked files automatically and stage them:

```
git add -u .
```

This will add all changes (additions, modifications and file removals) of all tracked files in the current directory. If you leave off the dot at the end, it applies to the whole repository (so you have less control over it).

Comment: "Modifying a file in the repo... And deleting a file from the repository is a change where you delete the file"
Oh, how wonderful! That's all what i needed, excelent note. Thanks so much!